# Java Access Bridge installation doesn't work on a 64bit machine?

Tags: java, c#, .net, java-access-bridge

I'm trying to get [JAB](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/accessibility/accessbridge/index.jsp) working so I can scrape some text out of a java window, but its failing horribly.

The odd thing is that while it **doesn't work on my machine** it *does* work on other machines.

My machine:  7, 64bit
Works on:  7 32bit (2 boxes tested), XP 32bit

The common thing appears that if you *don't* install the JAB setup application from Sun, as I haven't done on my dev machine, it doesn't work.  If you *do* install the setup application, it appears to work.

Process Monitor doesn't show that any DLLs cannot be located during execution.

Has anyone encountered this issue before?  Is the only solution to install the binaries from Sun?  Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.  [Unprofessional rant removed... *damn you, diamond!*]  Steps to JAB on a 64bit box:

1. Download latest version of the JAB **MANUAL INSTALL** package: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/accessibility/accessbridge/index.jsp
2. Update Java if you haven't.  Don't be a jerk.
3. Unblock the zip if you haven't and then unzip to some folder
4. Get thee into the InstallerFiles directory you just unzipped
5. Move all DLL files into %SystemRoot%\sysWow64.  Files are:  JavaAccessBridge.dll, JAWTAccessBridge.dll, WindowsAccessBridge.dll
6. Move the required .jar files into the specified java folder.  If you are running JRE6 you are copying `jaccess-1_4.jar` and `access-bridge.jar` to `c:\program files (x86)\java\jre6\lib\ext`.  Depending on when you read this you might have to check the docs to figure out what jar files to place in what locations.  Sucks, I know.
7. Move the file `accessibility.properties` to the root directory of the JRE:  `c:\program files (x86)\java\jre6\lib`.  **FAILURE TO DO THIS BREAKS JAB**.  If you place this file in the `lib` folder it will not work.  This is the twist that will screw you for two days.
8. Don't bother altering your Path system variable.  It doesn't matter on 64bit XP or 7.

If anything, number 7 is going to screw up more people than any of them as the documentation isn't clear as to where this file goes.

Comment: There is a readme (which doesnt appear with the installation, but is present on download.java.net), and gives better instructions of installing JAB on 64 bit systems: [Readme](http://download.java.net/accessbridge/2.0.2/promoted/b03/README.txt)